# How to check the NFT timelock status?

Tags: cardano-cli, nft, cardano-serialization-lib

How can I check the NFT timelock status, besides pool.pm?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the original script policy to see the lock status (see these *slot* and *before*).

```
$ cat policy.script
{ "type": "all", "scripts": [ { "slot": 24285375, "type": "before" }, { "keyHash": "e97316c52c85eab276fd40feacf78bc5eff74e225e744567140070c3", "type": "sig" } ] }
```

From that, you can calculate the policy id of it.

```
$ cardano-cli transaction policyid --script-file ./policy.script
00000002df633853f6a47465c9496721d2d5b1291b8398016c0e87ae
```

There is no way to reverse this process. You really need to original minting policy.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Marek, although there is a manual way to do it.

Let's try the policy of Spacebudz:

1. You can find the policy in [cardano scan](https://cardanoscan.io/tokenPolicy/d5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc)
2. Go to the *small script* button at the left side of the policy id.
3. You can check there the `invalidAfter` slot
4. Using that slot, you can check in any tool (i.e. `cardano-cli` or [explorer.cardano.org](https://explorer.cardano.org/en)) the current slot to determine if the policy is locked or not.